# Page auto reloading for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, knockout.js

I am having a bug with a project that I am finding very hard to reproduce but it is a serious bug. As part of my attempt to fix it, I would like to know the answer to the following question: what could cause a page to refresh by itself?

It's an MVC project, written in C# + Razor.

More specifically, the initial page load fetches via Ajax some appointment objects to populate a calendar (for booking). The calendar is written with Knockout code.

What is happening is the page loads, showing appointments, but very very quickly it reloads showing no appointments. A manual refresh brings them back.

Can anyone think any avenues to explore as to what could cause this? It seems browser and computer independent.

Comment: Sounds like client-side code is likely to blame.  I would start by adding some `debugger;` statements to various points in the Javascript code to act as breakpoints.  A good first candidate for where to do this might be at the end of Ajax event that you indicated runs on initial page load.  This will help you validate your theory about what you see at load, versus what you see on subsequent 'auto-refresh' as you are calling it.

Comment: @DavidTansey great idea. It might only be defeated by the fact that this is a one-in-fifty bug, so if I put a breakpoint and don't see the bug happen before it, I'm still never 100% sure that I got rid of it :...)

Comment: I'd add a debugger on the beforeunload event and use the stacktrace to step back to see the culprit